# Use of opencv waitkey() with C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to display the webcam feed with a timer but it doesn't render smoothly. Here is the code :

```
    int timer = 10;
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat img;

    while (true) {
        cap.read(img);
        
        if (timer == 0) {
            cout << "TIME'S UP !!!" << endl;
        }
        else if (timer <= 20) {
            imshow("Image", img);
            waitKey(1);
        }
        system("cls");
        cout << timer-- << " seconds left" << endl;
        Sleep(1000);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) instead, to keep calling `cv::imshow()` + `cv::waitKey` for 10s and end the loop.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

namespace ch = std::chrono;
using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    cv::Mat img;

    auto t0 = ch::system_clock::now();
    for (decltype(t0)::duration elapsed; elapsed < 10s; elapsed = ch::system_clock::now() - t0)  
    {
        if (cap >> img) {
            imshow("Image", img);
        }
        waitKey(1);
    }

    std::cout << "TIME'S UP !!!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: So I keep the `Sleep()` or I remove it ?

Comment: nah you don't need it.

Comment: But if you do, try using `std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s)` instead.

Comment: ```for (decltype(t0)::duration elapsed; elapsed < 25s; elapsed = ch::system_clock::now() - t0) {
        
       while (true) {
            cap.read(img);
            if (timer <= 20) {
                imshow("Image", img);
            }
            waitKey(1);
            system("cls");
            std::cout << timer-- << " seconds left" << endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "TIME'S UP !!!" << endl;```            I tried with what you said, is it good like that ?

Comment: Why did you keep the `while(true)` ? or the old `timer` variable? or the sleep call? You don't need any of that. Just compile/run the code I gave you; if it doesn't work, tell us why. If it does, just adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I did run your code, it works but it's not as smooth as I want.

Comment: The `cv::waitKey(1);` should be outside (just after) the `if` now that I think about it, so the window's refreshed whether there's a new image or not.